# Convert month year to a date in r

Tags: r, date, datetime

I need to convert following types of strings to a date format.

```
Convert "Feb 2009" to 2009-02-01
Convert "Jan 2010" to 2010-01-01
Convert "Mar 2011" to 2011-03-01
```

I can achieve this from the following code using `zoo` package.

```
as.Date(as.yearmon("Feb 2009"))
```

But due to some constraints I do not want to use this way of converting. So I want to know if there is any other way in R of achieving this task?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can paste `01` to the vector using `paste` and then convert to `date` by specifying the appropriate `format`

```
as.Date(paste('01', v1), format='%d %b %Y')
#[1] "2009-02-01" "2010-01-01", "2011-03-01"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Feb 2009", "Jan 2010", "Mar 2011")
```