# as.Date returning NA while converting it from character

Tags: r

I am converting following format to date from character

```
  January 2016
```

I want to convert it to following format

```
   201601
```

I am using following code

```
    df$date <- as.Date(df$date,"%B %Y")
```

But it returns me NA values. I have even set the locale as follows

```
    lct<- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
    Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME",lct)
```

But it gives me NA values. How to fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert month year to a date in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697399/convert-month-year-to-a-date-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this easily with `as.yearmon` and `format`

```
library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(str1), "%Y%m")
#[1] "201601"
```

---

If we are going by the `as.Date` route, then 'Date' requires day also, so, `paste` a day and then use `format` after converting to 'Date'

```
format(as.Date(paste(str1, '01'), "%B %Y %d") , "%Y%m")
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "January 2016"
```

Comment: how to find difference of above date format with current date e.g 201601 and 201510 should be in days

Comment: @Neil If you really wanted difference, then it is better to be in `Date` or in `yearmon` i.e. `as.yearmon(str1) - as.yearmon("201601", "%Y%m")
#[1] 0`