# R: Yearmon producing NA values

Tags: r, date, na, zoo

I am working with the R programming language.

I have data in the following form (May-18 = May 2018):

```
my_df = data.frame(
var1 = c(10,20,15),
var2 = c("Apr-18", "May-18", "Jun-18"))
```

Using this post ([Convert month year to a date in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697399/convert-month-year-to-a-date-in-r)), I am trying to convert var2 into a date format for plotting e.g. `plot(my_df$var1, my_df$var2, type = "l")`

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(my_df$var2))
```

But I get this error:

```
[1] NA NA NA
```

Can someone please show me a way to fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: `as.POSIXct(paste0(my_df$var2, "-01"), format = "%b-%y-%d", tz = "Europe/Berlin")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the right abbreviations `%b-%y` to your `as.yearmon` function like this:

```r
my_df = data.frame(
  var1 = c(10,20,15),
  var2 = c("Apr-18", "May-18", "Jun-18"))

library(zoo)
my_df$var2 = as.Date(as.yearmon(my_df$var2, "%b-%y"))

plot(my_df$var1, my_df$var2, type = "l")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell `zoo::as.yearmon()` what format your dates are in:

```
zoo::as.yearmon(my_df$var2, format = "%b-%y")

# [1] "Apr 2018" "May 2018" "Jun 2018"
```

Here, `%b` is the three letter month abbreviation, `-` indicates the the data-specific separator, and `%y` represents the 2-digit year.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! is it possible to have it like 2018-04-01, 2018-05-01?

Comment: @stats_noob whoops! I put the format for day, not year. See edit. Thanks for catching that! If you want the day, you shouldn't use `as.yearmon`. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to need `as.yearmon`, here; just use the right format in `as.Date`:

```r
as.Date(do.call(paste, my_df), format = "%d %b-%y")
#[1] "2018-04-10" "2018-05-20" "2018-06-15"
```

Or like this, for plotting:

```r
as.Date(paste("01", my_df$var2), format = "%d %b-%y")
#[1] "2018-04-01" "2018-05-01" "2018-06-01"

my_df$var2 <- as.Date(paste("01", my_df$var2), format = "%d %b-%y")
plot(my_df$var1, my_df$var2, type = "l")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! is it possible to have it like 2018-04-01, 2018-05-01?

Comment: Yes, you can use paste

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to convert it to Date class to plot it. plot.zoo will plot yearmon data, autoplot.zoo will plot it using ggplot2 and xyplot.zoo will plot it using lattice.  Note that the format of the data must be specified when converting to yearmon if not in the default format that as.yearmon assumes.

```
library(zoo)
my_df |>
  read.zoo(index = 2, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%b-%y") |>
  plot(xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

or using ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
my_df |>
  read.zoo(index = "var2", FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%b-%y") |>
  autoplot() + labs(x = "", y = "")
```

or using lattice

```
library(lattice)
library(zoo)
my_df |>
  read.zoo(index = "var2", FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%b-%y") |>
  xyplot(xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

The plot output looks  like this. The others are similar but not identical.

[image: screenshot]